# odd output from DifferenceDelta

Tags: symbolic, polynomials, core-language

I would appreciate an explanation of why `DifferenceDelta` produces a complicated expression for a simple quadratic.  I see that this is caused by the Real value `0.1`, but I do not understand the rationale.  Note that even `FullSimplify` does not help much here.

```
f = Function[x, 15 + 2 x - 0.1 x^2]
DifferenceDelta[f[i], i]  
(* -((0.2 (-9.5 + 1. i) (-150. - 20. i + 1. i^2))/((-25.8114 + 1. i) (5.81139 + 1. i))) *)
```

Note: Mma 12.0 on up to date Win 10.

Comment: Good question. It is correct up to a some rounding error, though: `DifferenceDelta[f[i], i] // Apart` returns `1.9 - 0.2 i - 1.79755*10^-15/(-25.8114 + 1. i) + 1.79755*10^-15/(
 5.81139 + 1. i)`.

Comment: "Note that even `FullSimplify` does not help much here." - indeed. But, the situation is salvageable: `With[{expr = DifferenceDelta[f[i], i]}, PolynomialQuotient[Numerator[expr], Denominator[expr], i]]`. Alternatively: `DiscreteShift[f[i], i] - f[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following works correctly.

```
f = Function[x, 15 + 2 x - 0.100000000000000000000* x^2];
DifferenceDelta[f[i], i] // FullSimplify
(*1.900000000000 - 0.2000000000000 i *)
```

The same phenomenon appears for other commands, e.g. `Residue`.

PS. To be clear,

```
g = Function[x, 15 + 2 x - 0.123456789101121314* x^2];
DifferenceDelta[g[i], i] // FullSimplify
(*1.8765432109 - 0.2469135782022 i*)
```

, but

```
g = Function[x, 15 + 2 x - 0.12345678910112131* x^2];
DifferenceDelta[g[i], i] // FullSimplify
 (*(-228. + i (-0.4 + i (5.87654 + (-0.246914 + 1.37065*10^-17 i) i)))/(-121.5 + 
  i (-16.2 + 1. i)) *)
```

Comment: Exact numbers work.

Comment: @Alan: You open an opened door. Decimals with many digits work too as I demonstrate.